# Why environment import is importing a Module (Angular 14)?

Tags: angular, importerror

I'm importing the `environment` const from the `environment.ts` file and, as you can see from the image below, I have a `Module` reference instead of a constant...

I'm going crazy...what is happening?

[image]

My environment.ts file is something like this:

```
export const environment = {
   ...
}
```

and this is how I'm importing it

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
```

I'm using Angular 14 and the fileReplacement configuration is set like this

```
"fileReplacements": [
   {
      "replace": "projects/nr-b2b/src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "projects/nr-b2b/src/environments/environment.localdev.ts"                                 
   }
]
```

This the serve script

```
ng serve --project=nr-b2b --configuration=localdev
```